# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) на Android L

Tags: java, android, jni

Библиотека: [Git](https://github.com/jaeguly/libmediainfo).
Все работает прекрасно! На андроиде младше лоллипоп.
на пятом вот так

**куски logcat**

```
...
12-08 16:46:02.084: A/libc(15075): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6d0081 in tid 15075 (nfo.android.app)
...
12-08 19:35:34.494: A/libc(18482): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xd in tid 18482 (nfo.android.app)
...
12-08 20:02:50.994: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM*, void*)() is called.
12-08 20:02:50.994: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): JNI_VERSION_1_6 OK!
12-08 20:02:50.994: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): Registering org/mediainfo/android/MediaInfo natives
12-08 20:02:50.995: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM*, void*)() will be returned.
12-08 20:02:50.995: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): jlong MediaInfo_create(JNIEnv*, jobject)() is called.
12-08 20:02:51.133: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): MediaInfo->New() ok! -1276506360
12-08 20:02:51.133: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): jlong MediaInfo_create(JNIEnv*, jobject)() will be returned.
12-08 20:03:07.163: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): jint MediaInfo_open(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong, jstring)() is called.
12-08 20:03:07.163: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): The mediainfo handle is -1276506360
12-08 20:03:07.289: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): MediaInfo->Open('/sdcard/P_20141220_104431.jpg') returns 1
12-08 20:03:07.289: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): jint MediaInfo_open(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong, jstring)() will be returned.
12-08 20:03:59.768: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): The mediainfo handle is -1276506360
12-08 20:03:59.769: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): MediaInfo->Option('Complete', ..) returns ''.
12-08 20:04:03.569: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): The mediainfo handle is -1276506360
12-08 20:04:03.570: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): MediaInfo->Option('Inform', ..) returns ''.
12-08 20:04:07.555: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): The mediainfo handle is -1276506360
12-08 20:04:07.558: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): MediaInfo->Inform() returns 'General
12-08 20:04:07.558: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): Complete name                            : /sdcard/P_20141220_104431.jpg
12-08 20:04:07.558: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): Format                                   : JPE'.
12-08 20:05:15.458: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): void MediaInfo_close(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong)() is called.
12-08 20:05:15.458: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): The mediainfo handle is -1276506360
12-08 20:05:15.458: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): void MediaInfo_close(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong)() will be returned.
12-08 20:05:23.801: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): void MediaInfo_destroy(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong)() is called.
12-08 20:05:23.801: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): The mediainfo handle is -1276506360
12-08 20:05:23.801: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): MediaInfo->Destroy() ok! -1276506360
12-08 20:05:23.801: D/libmediainfo-jni(19030): void MediaInfo_destroy(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong)() will be returned.
12-08 20:05:31.432: A/libc(19030): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xb444c000 in tid 19030 (diainfo.android)
```

Обычно пишут, что из-за не засинхронизированности потоков и еще там всякую ерунду про сохранение gson в SharedPreferences - это не мой случай. Я упростил все вообще до одного класса и одднооо потока - проблема таже.
К тому же, а может и это причина, результат работы либы - строка в непонятной кодировке, символы похожи на китайские иероглифы, на android 4.4 все прекрасно.

Почему и как исправить такое разное поведения на разных версиях андроида?

В общем, не пойму куда копать, по логу видно, что либа отрабатывает, а падение уже после.

Компиляция с APP_PLATFORM := android-21, положительных результатов не дает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем ошибка была в исходниках, автор изобрел "велосипед" для преобразования типов jstring в wchar_t, который и не "ехал" на пятом андройде. Пришлось сдать свой "велосипед".